# Robolectric and AndroidX ClassNotFoundException android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Style

Tags: android, junit, classnotfoundexception, robolectric

I am trying to use Robolectric in order to unit test some classes in an Android application without using an emulator or a device. I would like, for example, to unit test a Dao class but I always have the following exception :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Style

Here the fullstackstrace :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Style   at
>   com.pcg.ape.AudiencePlus.a(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.pcg.ape.AudiencePlus.initialize(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.company.app.AppApplication.onCreate(AppApplication.kt:360)    at
>   org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidEnvironment.lambda$installAndCreateApplication$0(AndroidEnvironment.java:253)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:75)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidEnvironment.java:253)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidEnvironment.java:149)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:298)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:247)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Style   at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.getByteCode(SandboxClassLoader.java:164)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:119)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$findClass$0(SandboxClassLoader.java:112)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:53)
>     at
>   org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.findClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:111)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 16 more

Note that the AudiencePlus library is a library in order to received push notifications (like OneSignal).

The project uses androidX. Here some configuration elements :

The `gradle.properties` file contains these lines :

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true
```

The `build.gradle` file of the app module contains these lines :

```
android
{
  defaultConfig
  {
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    testOptions
    {
      unitTests
      {
        includeAndroidResources = true
      }
    }
  }
}

dependencies
{
  testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
  testImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.1.1"
  testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.0"
  testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2"
}
```

Here the class I am trying to test :

```
package com.company.app.room.ecat.dao

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyDaoTest
{

  @Test
  fun myMethodTest()
  {

  }

}
```

Note that I try all the "Shorten command line" options into the the "Run/Debug Configurations" menu.

The "none" one does not compile (too long arguments) and all other work with the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Anyone can help me ? Why does it try to load a non-androidx class ?